# UITable does not scroll smoothly and cells show wrong info in IOS

Tags: ios, caching, asynchronous, uitableview, loading

I have an UITable with just 6 custom cells. Each CustomCell have a horizontal scroll view which have custom Views into it. Each CustomView has a ImageView and Text on it.

So to put it all together it may look like this

UITable --> CustomCell ---> Horizontal ScrollView --> CustomView --> ImageView and Text

Here is the code for Cell in UITable

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MySecondIdentifier = @"MySecondIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MySecondIdentifier];

    if(cell2 == nil){

        cell2 = [(CustomCell* )[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MySecondIdentifier target:self row:indexPath.row parent:self]; 

    }
    [cell2 setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell2 setValueToCellViewItem:tempTitleString setOfImage:dictCatData];
    return cell2;

}
```

where DictCatData = NSMutableArray of data nodes
and tempTitleString = Title string for the cell (using it for some other purpose)

Here is how I set a CustomCell values

```
- (void) setValueToCellViewItem:(NSString *)pTitle setOfImage:(NSMutableArray *)catData{
[the_pScrolView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([catData count] * 107 , 107)];

int counter = 0;
for(NSDictionary *tempDict in catData){

    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc]init];
    url = [tempDict objectForKey:@"main_img_url"];
    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    UIImageView *mSdWebImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(counter * 107, 0, 107, 107)];
    [mSdWebImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:nil];
    [mSdWebImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [the_pScrolView addSubview:mSdWebImage];

    ///Setting the title properties
    UILabel *the_pLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((counter * 107) + 15, 85, 97, 22)];
    the_pLable.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    the_pLable.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0];
    the_pLable.numberOfLines = 1;
    the_pLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    the_pLable.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"title"];

    [the_pScrolView addSubview:the_pLable];
    counter++;

}
```

I am using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for async downloading and caching as I think thats the best we have on net.

The ScrollView can contain images ranging from 0 to 30+ images

When I open this page on my iPhone, the images are getting downloaded an cached properly I guess, as I am able to see them with no difficulties

My Problem are

1. When I try to scroll up and down the table, the scrolling is not smooth. So how can I make it more smoother without effecting the background image downloading and caching
2. When I scroll the table up and down several times, the custom cells are redrawn I guess so the CustomCells with no images (i.e. no customViews in scrollView) show the images from other custom cells below/top.

Sometimes the app crashes, I guess this is issue of memory management.

Comment: I deleted my answer so that your question could get more attention as new.

Answer (score 0):

How big are the images being downloaded? I had similar issues (without the extra horizontal scrolling) and I was able to fix it by using actual thumbnails of the images instead of the actual images (in the TableView).

You may want to try downloading, caching, and creating thumbnails of the images in a separate object and then letting the TableViewCell load those thumbnails of the images instead of the actual images.

This sped up scrolling perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the reused cells showing wrong images, simply remove the images in cellForRowAtIndexPath before calling your code to display new images. That way if the images are delayed, at least the old ones have been removed or hidden.